# Abstract and generic methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics, abstract-class

Having this abstract class:

```
abstract class OrderHandler<T> : Handler  where T : class
{
    protected readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseOrder, T>> OrderDispatcher =
         new Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseOrder, T>>
    {
        { typeof(OrderA), order => HandleOrder((OrderA) order) },
        { typeof(OrderB), order => HandleOrder((OrderB) order) },
        { typeof(OrderC), order => HandleOrder((OrderC) order) },
        { typeof(OrderD), order => HandleOrder((OrderD) order) },
    };

    public abstract T HandleOrder(OrderA order);

    public abstract T HandleOrder(OrderB order);

    public abstract T HandleOrder(OrderC order);

    public abstract T HandleOrder(OrderD order);
}

abstract class Handler
{
    public abstract Start(string orderId);
}
```

And I want make specific Handler classes that have access to the dispacher dictionary but each one overrides and implements its own HandleOrder methods.

I can't seem to apply that generic `T` to the dictonary's delegate.

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT*

I want to have multiple classes inheriting OrderHandler such as InsertOrderHandler, DeleteOrderHandler, UpdateOrderHandler, etc.
There are many Order objects (A, B, C, ...) and they all inherit BaseOrder.

I already have a method that returns an BaseOrder object but i need to know which one of the subclasses it is.

```
BaseOrder order = GetOrder(id);
```

So to avoid doing

```
if (order is OrderA) else if (order is OrderB) ...
```

I created the HandleOrder methods that are delegated by type.

Basically

```
class InsertOrderHandler : OrderHandler<InsertOrderResult>
{
    public override Start(string orderId)
    {
        Order o = GetOrder(orderId);
        InsertOrderResult i = OrderDispatcher[o.GetType()](orderId);
    }

    public override InsertOrderResult HandleOrder(OrderA order)
    { /* do something then insert order */ }

    ...
}

class UpdateOrderHandler : OrderHandler<UpdateOrderResult>
{
    public override Start(string orderId)
    {
        Order o = GetOrder(orderId);
        UpdateOrderResult u = OrderDispatcher[o.GetType()](orderId);
    }

    public override UpdateOrderResult HandleOrder(OrderA order)
    { /* do something then update order */ }

    ...

class DeleteOrderHandler : OrderHandler<DeleteOrderResult>
{
    public override Start(string orderId)
    {
        Order o = GetOrder(orderId);
        DeleteOrderResult d = OrderDispatcher[o.GetType()](orderId);
    }

    public override DeleteOrderResult HandleOrder(OrderA order)
    { /* do something then delete order */ }

    ...
 }
```

I start the handler like this

```
new InsertOrderHandler().Start("123");
```

Comment: How can a method be `abstract` as well as `static`?

Comment: So far, no answer below can help you. It will be easy to help if you can say what you're trying to achieve with more context. I hope you read [my comment over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783768/abstract-and-generic-methods#comment36578004_23783787)

Comment: Edited the question... i think it's more clear now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the generic constraint to the class:

```
abstract class OrderHandler<T> where T : class
```

*NOTE:*
As Sriram already said in his comment: A method can not be `static` and `abstract` as you can not `override` `static`-methods.

So the following does not work:

```
public abstract static T HandleOrder<T>(OrderA order);
```

You need to use:

```
public abstract T HandleOrder(OrderA order); // no <T> as defined on class level
```

Then you can `override` them in you custom handler. Of course you need an object instance to call the methods then and the `OrderDispatcher` also needs to be non-`static` to access the instance methods.

**Possible solution for updated question:**

```
abstract class OrderHandler<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseOrder, T>> OrderDispatcher;

    public OrderHandler()
    {
       OrderDispatcher = new Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseOrder, T>>
       {
            { typeof(OrderA), order => HandleOrder(order as OrderA) },
            { typeof(OrderB), order => HandleOrder(order as OrderB) },
            // ...
       };
    }

    public T HandleOrder(BaseOrder order)
    {
        return OrderDispatcher[order.GetType()](order);
    }
    protected abstract T HandleOrder(OrderA order);
    // ...
}

class InsertOrderHandler : OrderHandler<InsertOrderResult>
{
    protected override InsertOrderResult HandleOrder(OrderA order)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var handler = new InsertOrderHandler();
handler.HandleOrder(order);
```

Comment: No, still there is some fundamental problem. `OrderDispatcher` `Dictionary` is static, so static field initializer can't access instance methods(neither the instance field initializer can). I believe something wrong with the design itself.

Comment: Agree with @SriramSakthivel. Seems 5 people have upvoted an answer that can't work.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Added that - forgot about that, thanks.
@DanielKelley: It "can work" if also the `OrderDispatcher` is not `static`, but I also agree with Sriram, that it seems like a design problem in general...

Comment: @chrfin A point that was previously missing from your answer when I made my comment.

Comment: Updated again: Now tested and working code. See the following LINQPad-Snippet: http://pastebin.com/QTtdpEzV

Answer (score 0):

Define it as:

```
abstract class OrderHandler<T>
```